# spring 3.1 setting profile

Tags: spring, profile

I want to start using profile in Spring 3.1 and i found a problem.

In my hibernate xml file i've set

```
<beans profile="test">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/springtest.properties" />


</beans>

<beans profile="production">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />


</beans>
```

And in web.xml i've set:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>production</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

but when i'm trying to run application i have issue, that spring doesn't see variables from `spring.properties` file.

Should i set something else ?

**UPDATE**

hibernate file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />


    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven/> -->

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.app.search">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.UsersEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.CategoryEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.GroupEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PlacesEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.ProvincesEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageAreaEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageConfigurationEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageTemplateEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageTypeEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageModuleEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageModuleAreaConfigurationEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageModuleConfigurationEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageFacetEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageFacetAreaEntity</value>
                <value>com.app.search.domain.PageTemplateFacetEntity</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/Search</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password"></prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${search.jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${search.jdbc.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${search.jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
        <qualifier value="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <beans profile="test">

        <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/springtest.properties" />


    </beans>

    <beans profile="production">

        <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    </beans>



</beans>
```

Comment: Seems to be the correct behavior, you have activated the production profile and production profile is loading up the `springdev.properties` file, if you want spring.properties file to be loaded up, you have to activate the `test` profile right?

Comment: it doesn't matter which file will be loaded, cose both are these same. Now i'm just testing this solution of using profile, but i have problem with turn it on.

Comment: Okay, is the `<beans profile="test..and prod..` the last lines in the bean definition file? that is a caveat with Spring profiles definition.

Comment: Yes, i've added file with profiles above...

Comment: I'm not sure if spring doesn't see the declaration of profile type variable, or the profiles are wrong declarated...

Comment: I have added an answer, you have to set the profile slightly differently for the profile to picked up by ContextLoaderListener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the reason is that since you want this in your root application context, loaded up through ContextLoaderListener, the way to specify profile is not through the DispatcherServlet's init param, but ServletContext's init param, this way in your web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but this what i did based on http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/ article, where the variable is delared as init-param. I saw many articles where also params are declared in init-param.